# applicationShouldTerminate not called in AppDelegate and NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification not being sent

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, macos-catalina

I'm on XCode 11.1 on latest Catalina and none of my app's quit events are being called. applicationShouldTerminate in the AppDelegate nor do I get NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification if I observe it from anywhere. This is from the default quit behavior (Using the menu quit command, Command-Q, or closing the window with applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed returning YES) from the XCode app template using the default storyboard.

This happens with a brand new Xcode project template (If I start a new macOS "App" template, then add the applicationShouldTerminate method to the app delegate).

Other delegate methods like applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed are being called.

Am I doing something horribly wrong or is something messed up with Catalina?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I figured it out and it's because it seems that `NSSupportsSuddenTermination` is on by default now.

To disable sudden termination, set this boolean property to `NO` in the app's information property list file `Info.plist`:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

NSSupportsSuddenTermination is also called 'Application can be killed immediately when user is shutting down or logging out' within Xcode, and seems enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Info.plist for your project and find "Application can be killed immediately when user is shutting down or logging out" key. Changes its value to "No"